# sql, using join with renamed columns

Tags: sql, cloudera, hue

I've got two tables with similarly named columns, and I want to do a join on them.  So I have to rename the columns

Table1

```
|--------------------|------------------|
|      col1           |     col2         |
|--------------------|------------------|
|          1         |         5       |
|--------------------|------------------|
|          2         |         6       |
|--------------------|------------------|
|          3         |         7       |
|--------------------|------------------|
|          4         |         8       |
```

Table2

```
|--------------------|------------------|
|      col3          |     col2         |
|--------------------|------------------|
|          10        |         5       |
|--------------------|------------------|
|          11        |         6       |
|--------------------|------------------|
|          12        |         7       |
|--------------------|------------------|
|          13        |         8       |
```

What I want

```
|--------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      col1          |     col2         |     col3         |
|--------------------|------------------|
|          1         |         5       |         10       |
|--------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2         |         6       |         11       |
|--------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          3         |         7       |         12       |
|--------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          4         |         8       |         13       |
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to order the code properly

```
select col1 as T1_col1,
      col2 as T1_col2
from Table1 as T1
inner join 
    (select col3 as T2_col3,
        col2 as T2_col2
     from Table2 as T2)
    on T1.T1_col2 = T2.T2_col2
```

what's the right way to do this?

Comment: should be " on T1.col1 = T2.col2 "since you are not changing the column name but using an alias. Then do order by using the alias column you used (like T1_col1, etc..)

Comment: I used your advice and it helped; can you explain what am I doing with the `col2 as T1_col2`? It seems like it doesn't do anything

Comment: tell us how would you sort the data? you can use the column alias in "order by" BUT NOT in "ON" during join.

Comment: ok, another problem.  the select isn't including any columns from table 2

Comment: it is very hard for us to know what the problem is without 1) sample data 2) sample output 3) what is wrong with the output 4) what result you want. I cannot read your mind

Comment: added input/desired output, thanks!

Comment: please see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're asking but I believe that you just need to take the second table alias outside the parenthesis, everything else seems fine to me.

```
select T1.col1 as T1_col1,
  T2.col2 as T2_col2 --assuming you want col2 from table 2, otherwise your join would make no sense...
from Table1 as T1
inner join 
(select col3 as T2_col3,
    col2 as T2_col2
 from Table2)T2
on T1.col2 = T2.col2
```

Comment: i did this, but also had to use `T1.col2` instead of `T1.T1_col2` any idea why?

Comment: It's because as long as the table names are different (which they will be, for you wouldn't be able to name them the same thing if they're on the same DB) it doesn't matter if they have columns with the same name. You don't have to use a column alias (and you can't) to join them. Extra edit: A column alias will help you recognize a column better in case of duplicate names when coming from different tables or for readability causes when looking at a select's output.

Comment: ok, another problem.  the select isn't including any columns from table 2

Comment: I reused your query and didnt change much other than the alias thing, but if you closely look at it, you´re not really specifying where the columns you're selecting come from out of the two tables, however, judging by what you're selecting, which is T1_Col1 and T1_Col2, you're not trying to get anything from Column 2. Specify the table alias you want the results from on the select, like this: select T1.col1 as T1_col1, T2.col2 as T2.col2 (or whatever columns you want from whichever tables you want).
  col2 as T1_col2

Comment: I think I understand now.  the format is `<select stuff> from  <A join B>` not `<select stuff from A> join <stuff from B>`

Comment: Yeah, select <everything you want, specifying the table you want it from> from table1 inner join table2 ON table1.column = table2.column...

Answer (score 2):

You don't need column alias anyway.  You can use table alias instead and use it throughout your query.

```
select T1.col1,
       T1.col2,
       T2.col3
from  Table1 as T1
inner join 
   Table2 as T2
   on T1.col2 = T2.col2
order by T1.col1, 
         T1.col2;
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax needs to be corrected, I have used and edited your own query for the desired results:

```
WITH Table1 AS(
SELECT 1 COL1, 5 COL2 FROM DUAL
UNION 
SELECT 2     , 6  FROM DUAL
UNION 
SELECT 3     , 7  FROM DUAL
UNION 
SELECT 4     , 8  FROM DUAL)
, Table2 AS(
SELECT 10 COL3, 5 COL2 FROM DUAL
UNION 
SELECT 11     , 6 FROM DUAL
UNION 
SELECT 12     , 7 FROM DUAL
UNION 
SELECT 13     , 8 FROM DUAL
)
/*
SELECT
COL1, TAB2.COL2, COL3
FROM TAB1
JOIN TAB2
ON TAB1.COL2 = TAB2.COL2;
*/
Select col1 as T1_col1,
      col2 as T1_col2,
      T2_COL3
from Table1 T1
inner join 
    (select col3 as T2_col3,
        col2 as T2_col2
     from Table2 )T2
    on T1.col2 = T2.T2_col2;
```